# Automatically fit elements in flex layout

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I'm stuck with something it's easier to explain with this sample code

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.square} />
        <View style={styles.square} />
        <View style={styles.square} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  row: {
    height: 100,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  square: {
    aspectRatio: 1,
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "green",
  }
});

export default App;
```

At the moment I'm simply drawing 3 green squares inside a red row with a fixed height of 100.

On every device I'll probably have these 3 squares followed by some "free space" on the right. (picture 1)

If the row height is increased, the "free space" on the right is reduced, up to the point the squares exceeds the available width. (picture 2)

Now, I can't have these 3 squares to automatically fit the page, leaving the "free space" only on their bottom when the row height is big enough. (picture 3 and 4)

I could play around *onLayout* prop or I could do some kind of math on element sizes, but I'd like to keep it simple and try to understand if the issue can be solved using flexbox the correct way.

A couple of pictures to better explain the scenario:

[image: Case 1]
[image: Case 2]

Above how it works right know. picture 1 is ok. Picture 2 is something I don't want. When the row height is not enough to contain the squares, it should act like the pictures below.

[image: Case 3]
[image: Case 4]

Fiddle [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-shockley-cuj86)

Comment: How green squares should react when page is getting smaller? Should they go to new row?

Comment: @JacekRatajewski nope, they must stay on the same row

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `align-items: baseline` style to the container, and make the `.square` items to `flex-grow: 1` like this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 500,
    alignItems: 'baseline',
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  square: {
    aspectRatio: 1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    margin: 20
  }
});
```

the `align-items` arrange the flex items with their default width, and the `flex-grow` property will make the items grow to fill the width of the container, and since the flex grow is equal the items growth will be equal across the containers

if you want the `.square` items to be in the center, you only need to change the `align-items` property

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-greider-8ke8b I tried with row height 30 and squares don't resize to fit that height

Comment: row height: 30 + margin around the square of 20px , would be itself some sort of an issue .:) @c.bear

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yep, I noticed that while I was posting :) 50 is probably better

Comment: oops you're right! this is kinda tricky because at one point you're looking at the width but it changes into height. i'll try to see if i can come up with something